# Why am I getting an incorrect answer from Bayes probability rule?

Tags: solution-verification, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The original question follows:

> 4. If a [fair] coin is flipped 16 times, what is the probability of landing exactly 5 heads given that at least 3 of the flips landed heads?

**Approach 1- Bayes Rule**
My mistake is probably related to **.

I tried to apply Bayes rule.
$$ P( \space A|B \space ) = \frac{P(\space B|A\space) * P(\space A\space)}{P(\space B \space)}$$
A = exactly 5 heads.

B = 3 heads.  **Do I need $_{16}C_3 \space +\space _{16}C_4\space +\space 
 _{16}C_5\space ..._{16}C_{16} $ instead?
Hmmm, do I need to factor in that the three heads must occur in the first 14 flips?  Seems like that's not sufficient

$P( \space B|A\space) = 1$, because to get 5 heads, we first must get 3 heads.

$P(\space A\space) = _{16}C_5$

$P(\space B\space) = _{16}C_3$

Then $$ P( A|B) = \frac{_{16}C_5*(\frac12)^{16}}{_{16}C_3*(\frac12)^{16}}$$
Cancelling, this becomes $$\frac{13*12}{5*4}$$
Which is obviously incorrect.

**Approach 2**
So then I tried by each case.

$\begin{array}{|l|l|} \hline
\text{Description}&\text{Related Formula}\\\hline
\text{Begins with 3 tosses including exactly 3 heads}&_{3}C_3 *\space _{13}C_2 * (\frac12)^{16}\\
\text{Begins with 4 tosses including exactly 3 heads }&_{4}C_3 *\space _{12}C_2* (\frac12)^{16}\\ \vdots &\vdots\\
\text{Begins with 14 tosses including exactly 3 heads}&_{14}C_{3} *\space _{2}C_2* (\frac12)^{16}\\\hline
\end{array}$

Which sums to
$$\sum_{i=1} ^{12} \space _{i+2}C_3\space * _{14-i}C_2*(\frac12)^{16}$$
Since each row in the table or term in the sum is mutually exclusive I can simply add all the probabilities.  The 2nd approach seems better.  Is it correct?  And if so please explain why Bayes rule fails.

Comment: $P(B) = 1 - P(no heads) - P(one head) - P(two heads) = 1 - (0.5^{16}) - {16 \choose 1}(0.5)^{16} - {16 \choose 2}(0.5)^{16}$

Comment: That would be a way to find $P(  3 to 16 heads ) $ but says nothing about conditional probability A given B.

Comment: Also, my table shows up correctly in the edit/ rough draft window, but incorrectly in the published version.  Why is that?

Comment: What does "given that at least of the flips land heads" mean?

Comment: That was a typo.  I corrected it to say "...given that at least **two** of the flips landed heads?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And if so please explain why Bayes rule fails.

You were just not using the right events.  You were using "exactly 3" when you needed "at least 3".

> The 2nd approach seems better. Is it correct?

It is better, but certainly not correct. You do not need the condition: "begins with three heads," or anything like that.

> Hmmm, do I need to factor in that the three heads must occur in the first 14 flips?

No, because the condition is just that there are *at least* three heads *somewhere* among the sixteen tosses.

**Don't add unnecessary constraints.**

---

> > If a [fair] coin is flipped 16 times, what is the probability of landing exactly 5 heads given that at least three of the flips land heads?
>
> Do I need $\def\C#1#2{{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}}\C{16}3 +\C{16}4+ \C{16}3 \ldots \C{16}{16}$ instead?  See note**.

Yes, because the condition is that it is *at least*, rather than exactly.

Although this is **also** $2^{16}-\C{16}0-\C{16}1-\C{16}2$, by the Binomial Expansion Theorem.

---

Let $H$ be the count for heads among sixteen tosses of a fair coin:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(H=5\mid H\geq 3) & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(H=5)}{1-\mathsf P(H\lt 3)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\C{16}5}{2^{16}-\C{16}0-\C{16}1-\C{16}2}\cdot\color{gray}{\require{cancel}\dfrac{\cancel{1/2^{16}}}{\cancel{1/2^{16}}}}\end{align}$$

---

$\small\textbf{Note: }\{H=5\}=\{H=5\}\cap\{H\geq 3\}$

** $^{n}C_{r}$ is simply an alternate notation for $_{n}C_{r}$.

Comment: Overall, your answer makes perfect sense.  I'm likely to accept it as the answer in the next few days.

Clarification- I misspoke or mistyped, when I said "begins with exactly 3 H".  Without changing my formulas in the table, I clarified what those formulas meant.
"Begins with 3 tosses including exactly 3 heads"

Comment: Ok, I just worked out, that my 2nd approach is the same numerically as your numerator.
So if I correct my denominator to use your approach then we get the same results, but your method is simpler.
Numerator = 4368
Thank you so very much.

Try this in Wolfram "    Sum[((i+2) choose 3)*((14-i)choose 2),{i,1,12}]     "  and compare with $_{16}C_5$

Comment: Actually, your denominator is also incorrect.  Shouldn't it be 1- P( H < 2 ), then drops the 16 choose 2 term?  Because of "given that at least two of the flips landed heads?", we want to exclude P( H = 2 )  from the 1 - version of the denominator.

Comment: @nickalh Your original post indicated that it was at least three.  Albeit that had to be inferred from the events you were using.

Comment: Hmmm, somehow that got edited into the exercise incorrectly.  I checked the original.  You must be right.  I have edited this exercise.

Comment: Why are you using superscript preceding C in n choose r?
Would you mind if I edited it to be subscripts on both sides?  the website seems to be confusing "_n choose _r" with the markup code for italics.  The workaround seems to be use braces, "{, }" with both underscores.

Comment: Because it is [the notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#History_and_notation) I've been taught to use.